# Ubuntu 16.04 Login Loop Problem

Tags: 16.04, login, lightdm

I have a problem with ubuntu. When I tried login, I was seeing a black screen and again login screen was coming. I tried some codes but they didn't work. Codes which I tried;

```
chown username:username .Xauthority
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak
sudo chmod a+wt /tmp
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

However I creat a new account and it is working. Well, I want to use my main account but I can't work it. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and I solved it. Problem with login loop showed up after irregular shutdown. I have solved the problem as follows:

I saw that my home folder did not have **w** attribute.
I added **w** attribute and reboot.
Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and type in the console

```
sudo chmod -R +w ~
sudo reboot
```

Note: ~ home folder, +w add write attribute, -R recursive.
That's all.

Answer (score 0):

For me, for some reason, the owner of my home folder was changed to `root`. I just changed it back and I was able to login. Thankfully SSH was working for me so that I could make this change.

`sudo chown user:user user`

Answer (score 0):

I had login looping problem after upgrade of my old Thinkpad T-61p with nVidia Quadro FX 570M/PCIe/SSE2 graphics card. Right direction gave me [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/650253/852151), but hasn't helped either. So I start to look inside `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and there it was: my card was supported only by nvidia-340 driver. All what was needed was:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-340
sudo reboot
```

My learning: read content of  `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`